# webview.load(URLRequest view remains empty

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

Trying to learn iOS dev, but I have the following problem
`webview.load(URLRequest(url: url))` <- the view remains empty
this is the code I am using. I used story board to add a webkit view (as  Web View is depreciated), but it does not work as expected. using the loadHTMLString works

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!

        //load html string works
        //webview.loadHTMLString("<h1>Hello world!</h1>hi Marc", baseURL: nil)
        //load urlrequest does not work, no error, but empty view
        webview.load(URLRequest(url: url))

    }
```

Comment: Try : `webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!))`

Answer (score 1):

According to this talk on WWDC https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706/ you need to add this code on your Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

You can add this by:

1. Right Click on Info.plist
2. Open As/Source Code
3. Insert the code before this tag: < /plist >

Hope this help you ;)

**EDIT:**

This is for URLs with http. The url https://www.stackoverflow.com/ works because it has https. http://www.stackoverflow.com/ wouldn't work without the 's' or `NSAppTransportSecurity`.

Comment: thanks, this works, allthough other url worked without this piece of code

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is problem with given url. I have checked with other url like
https://www.myntra.com
https://www.google.com
https://www.apple.com. All are working with same code, however https://www.stackoverflow.com is not working. So might be Stackoverflow's site have some filtering on basis of web browser.

Comment: indeed, other url's work, but when I add the code from Guiseppe, this URL works also. thanks for your help